# Looking for a technical book

Tags: books

I'm looking for a book about digital photography that is dealing with the technical stuff in an exhaustive way. It maybe something like explaining from  what is a histogram to describing how sensors work, optic formulas etc... I had such a book for Video so I hope it exists for photography but I can't find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find a book that ranges from the basics, like what the histogram tells you, to advanced stuff like optical formulae. However, if you have a list of topics in mind you can create your own book with Wikipedia's [book creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&bookcmd=book_creator&referer=Image+sensor), which lets you compile a list of Wikipedia topics together into a single PDF or ODF file, or even order a printed copy.